# Showing company name on payment section in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment

I have successfully shown the company name by overriding the `Magento_Checkout/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html` file. And I tried to show the company name on the payment section, but not.

I tried the `address().company` code from `Magento214/vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/purchaseorder-form.html` file but it's throwing the error.

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, solved my self by extending `Magento_Checkout/template/billing-address/details.html`.

`requirejs-config.js` file extend the core file like below.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {

            'Magento_Checkout/template/billing-address/details.html':
                'CompanyName_ModuleName/template/billing-address/default.html'

        }
    }
};
```

`default.html` file extend the core file like below.

```
<div class="billing-address-details" data-bind="if: isAddressDetailsVisible() && currentBillingAddress()">
    <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().prefix --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().firstname --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().lastname --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().suffix --><!-- /ko -->,<br/>
    <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().company --><!-- /ko -->,<br/>
    <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().street --><!-- /ko -->,<br/>
    <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().city --><!-- /ko -->, <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().region --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().postcode --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: getCountryName(currentBillingAddress().countryId) --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().telephone --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: currentBillingAddress().customAttributes, as: 'element' } -->
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: Object.keys(element), as: 'attribute' } -->
    <!-- ko if: element[attribute].value != null -->
    <!-- ko text: element[attribute].value --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: element[attribute].value == null -->
    <!-- ko text: element[attribute] --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <button type="button"
            class="action action-edit-address"
            data-bind="visible: !isAddressSameAsShipping(), click: editAddress">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I have added the one line of code to above `<!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().company --><!-- /ko -->`.

After that execute the commands => `upgrade`, `static-content:deploy` and run Magentoento website.

Feel free to ask if it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same but it wasn't working then after I did R&D again and I seen your solution and it exactly same as I did. But still it's not working in my Magento 2.4.4.

I ran the all commands as well.

Thanks.